# DisplayLink Manager, BetterDisplay and HiDPI mode for 2k monitors on macOS 13

Tags: mac, multiple-monitors, resolution, external-display, high-dpi

I have been using a 2k monitor with my 2021 MacBook Pro "M1 Pro". The native resolution is 2560x1440. The macOS operating system does not think it is HiDPI and refuses to provide the HiDPI mode. If I want it to look like 1920x1080 (for larger text), I have to set scaling, then the display is actually set to 1920x1080 and the text becomes blur.

One day I found [BetterDisplay](https://github.com/waydabber/BetterDisplay), which can enable HiDPI mode on 2k monitor using dummies. This solved my need.

Until recently, my company decided to install some "fancy" DisplayLink docks. These docks help connect 2x monitors on the same Thunderbolt port, which is not natively supported by macOS. However, I find that this dock works by creating virtual displays. (I assume that is same with the dummies.) BetterDisplay cannot set HiDPI mode for their virtual displays. DisplayLink Manager itself does not create those virtual displays with HiDPI mode support either.

I tried for like a couple of hours, then I gave up and reverted back to my old setup. This consisted of connecting both monitors separately, but directly to my Thunderbolt/HDMI ports on the laptop, so BetterDisplay works again.

Is there any possible way to hack DisplayLink Manager or BetterDisplay to make this work?

Changing system font size (e.g. with Accessibility) is not an option for now, because I also need to use the same MacBook Pro on other setups and those setups look natively correct when using default font size.

Comment: What year MacBook? Apple Silicon or Intel?

Comment: @DavidAnderson M1 Pro.

Answer (score 0):

Your Mac can support 2 external monitors through either DisplayPort Alt mode or Thunderbolt. Since you only wish to connect two external monitors and DisplayLink technology probably slows down your Mac, the use of DisplayLink should be avoided.

Instead of using a DisplayLink dock, consider employing a Thunderbolt 3/4 hub/dock that is capable of supporting your two monitors. (I am being deliberately vague do to lack of information about your DisplayLink dock and monitors. Specifically, how are they connected?)

An example Thunderbolt 4 hub, which supports two monitors when used with your Mac, would be this OWC [Thunderbolt Hub](https://www.owc.com/solutions/thunderbolt-hub). If your monitors do not have DisplayPort compatible signal inputs, then USB-C adaptors (to whatever inputs your monitors have) would be required.

An example Thunderbolt 3 dock, which supports two monitors when used with your Mac, would be this OWC [Thunderbolt 3 mini Dock](https://www.owc.com/solutions/thunderbolt-3-mini-dock). This dock has two HDMI outputs.